# Downloading Steroids.js using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, steroids

I'm currently looking to download Appgyver's Steroids.js but keep running into the following problem:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is as I'm not very experienced with using Node.js as I doubt this problem is made by Appgyver's Steroids.js. I see that I have a version above what is required so I'm not sure where things are going wrong. Please any help in this matter would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

steroids.js requires very specific versions of node.js to run. Actually, the [installation page](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids_npm/installing/) says it requires node.js version 0.8.x. You are currenly using node.js version 0.10.15 which is why you are receiving this error.

I see you're on windows, so have a go with [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) to manage mulitple node.js versions.

Answer (score 0):

Steroids npm didn't support Windows until version 2.7.19. The latest version also supports Node.js 0.10.x and 0.11.x, so you should be good to go. See the updated install instructions at http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids_npm/installing/